# Is there a sorting routine faster than qsort?

Tags: c++, sorting

This is not an algorithmic question, but an implementation question.

I have a data structure that looks like:

```
struct MyStruct {
   float val;
   float val2;
   int idx;
}
```

I go through an array of about 40 million elements, and assign the 'val' fields to be the element, and the 'idx' field to be the index.

I'm then calling:

```
MyStruct* theElements = new MyStruct[totalNum];
qsort(theElements, totalNum, sizeof(MyStruct), ValOrdering);
```

and then, once I fill in val2, reversing the procedure with

```
qsort(theElements, totalNum, sizeof(MyStruct), IndexOrdering);
```

where

```
static int ValOrdering(const void* const v1, const void* const v2)
{
  if (((struct MyStruct*) v1)->val < ((struct MyStruct*) v2)->val)
    return -1;

  if (((struct MyStruct*) v1)->val> ((struct MyStruct*) v2)->val)
    return 1;

  return 0;
}
```

and

```
static int IndexOrdering(const void* const v1, const void* const v2)
{
  return ((struct MyStruct*) v1)->idx- ((struct MyStruct*) v2)->idx;
}
```

This setup takes 4 seconds to perform both sorts.  4 seconds seems like a long time for a sort of 40 million elements to take on a 3Ghz i5 processor; is there a faster approach?  I'm using vs2010 with the Intel Compiler (that has sorts, but not over structs like this that I can see).

**Update**:  Using std::sort shaves about 0.4 seconds off of the runtime, called like:

```
std::sort(theElements, theElements + totalPixels, ValOrdering);
std::sort(theElements, theElements + totalPixels, IndexOrdering);
```

and

```
bool GradientOrdering(const MyStruct& i, const MyStruct& j){
    return i.val< j.val;
}
bool IndexOrdering(const MyStruct& i, const MyStruct& j){
    return i.idx< j.idx;
}
```

adding the 'inline' keyword to the predicates does not seem to matter.  Since i have, and the spec allows for, a quad core machine, I'll check some kind of multithreaded sort next.

**Update 2**: Following @SirGeorge and @stark, I took a look at a single sort done via pointer redirects:

```
bool GradientOrdering(MyStruct* i, MyStruct* j){
    return i->val< j->val;
}
bool IndexOrdering(MyStruct* i, MyStruct* j){
    return i->idx< j->idx;
}
```

Even though there is just a single sorting call (to the GradientOrdering routine), the resulting algorithm takes 5 seconds, 1 second longer than the qsort approach.  It looks like std::sort is winning for now.

**Update 3**:  Looks like Intel's `tbb::parallel_sort` is the winner, taking the runtime of a single sort down to 0.5s on my system (so, 1.0s for both, which means that it's scaling pretty well from the original 4.0s for both).  I tried to go with a parallel fanciness proposed by Microsoft [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/01/26/how-to-pick-your-parallel-sort.aspx), but since I'm already using tbb and the syntax for `parallel_sort` is identical to the syntax for `std::sort`, I could use my earlier `std::sort` comparators to get everything finished.

I also used @gbulmer's suggestion (really, hitting-me-over-the-head realization) that I already have the original indeces, so instead of doing a second sort, I just need to assign a second array with the indeces from the first back into sorted order.  I can get away with this memory usage because I'm only deploying on 64bit machines with at least 4 gb of RAM (good to have these specs worked out ahead of time); without that knowledge, a second sort would be necessary.

@gbulmer's suggestion gives the most speedup, but the original question asked about fastest sort.  `std::sort` is the fastest single-threaded, `parallel_sort` is the fastest multithreaded, but no one gave that answer, so I'm giving @gbulmer the check.

Comment: `std::sort` = more type information and more inlining opportunity.

Comment: You could try multi-threaded merge sort.

Comment: Do you know anything about data distribution? Or is it completely random?

Comment: @MilanBabuškov-- it's pretty close to random, although I haven't done any kind of statistical analysis to prove that.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis-- thanks for the hint, checking it out now.

Comment: Are you walking the array in order to fill in val2 or do you need random access?

Comment: It might be interesting to just attempt 8 qsorts of 1/8 of the array in parallel, just to see how long that takes.  With intensive memory-accesses, there may not be much improvement. If there is substantial speedup, you could then mergeSort the 8 sections into one, perhaps again in multiple, parallel steps.  I'm not saying it would work, just that it could be tried..

Comment: What is it in the creating of val2 that requires the array to be sorted on val1?

Comment: What is the value of idx? Is it the original position in the array? Does idx change? If not, there is no need for a second sort pass. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data set is huge compared to cache, so it will be cache to memory limited.

Using indirection will make this worse because there is cache for the pointers, and memory is being accessed in a more random order, i.e. comparison isn't with neighbours. The program is working against any pre-fetch mechanisms in the CPU

Consider splitting the struct into two structs, in two arrays.

As an experiment, compare pass 1, with a pass one, where the struct is only `{ float val; int idx; };`

If it is cache and bandwidth bound, it should make a significant difference.

If cache locality is a key issue, it might be worth considering multi-way merges, or Shell sort; anything to improve locality.

Try sorting cache-size subsets of the records, then do multi-way merge sorts (might be worth looking at the processor cache manager spec to see if it is clear about the number of pre-fetch streams is tries to anticipate. Again, reducing the size of the data sets, by reducing the size of the structs streaming in from RAM may be q winner.

How is the idx field derived? It sounds like it is the original position in the array. Is it the index of the original record?

If that is the case, just allocate a second array, and copy the first into the second:

```
struct { float val; float val2; int idx } sortedByVal[40000000];
struct { float val; float val2 } sortedbyIdx[40000000];

for (int i=0; i<40000000; ++i) {
    sortedbyIdx[sortedByVal[i].idx].val = sortedByVal[i].val;
    sortedbyIdx[sortedByVal[i].idx].val2 = sortedByVal[i].val2;
}
```

There is no second sort. If that is is the case, merge the allocation of the val2 value with this pass.

Edit

I was curious, about relative performance, so I wrote a program to compare the 'library' C sort functions, qsort, mergesort, heapsort, and also compare sorting to idx with copy to idx. It also re-sorts sorted values, to get some handle on that. This is quite interesting too. I did not implemenet and test Shell sort, which often beats qsort in practice.

The program uses command line parameters to choose which sort, and whether to sort by idx, or just copy. Code: http://pastebin.com/Ckc4ixNp

The jitter on run-time is quite clear. I should have used CPU clocks, done many runs, and presented better results, but that is an 'exercise for the reader'.

I ran this on an old-ish MacBook Pro 2.2GHz Intel Core 2 Duo.
Some of the timing is OS C specific.

Timing (reformatted slightly):

```
qsort(data, number-of-elements=40000000, element-size=12)
Sorting by val - duration =            16.304194
Re-order to idx by copying - duration = 2.904821
Sort in-order data - duration =         2.013237
Total duration = 21.222251
User Time:       20.754574
System Time:      0.402959

mergesort(data, number-of-elements=40000000, element-size=12)
Sorting by val - duration =            25.948651
Re-order to idx by copying - duration = 2.907766
Sort in-order data - duration =         0.593022
Total duration = 29.449438
User Time:       28.428954
System Time:      0.973349

heapsort(data, number-of-elements=40000000, element-size=12)
Sorting by val - duration =            72.236463
Re-order to idx by copying - duration = 2.899309
Sort in-order data - duration =        28.619173
Total duration = 103.754945
User Time:       103.107129
System Time:       0.564034
```

**WARNING**: Those are single runs. Many runs would be needed to get reasonable statistics.

The code at pastebin actually sorts the 'reduced size', 8-byte array. On the first pass, only val and idx are needed, and as the array gets copied when val2 is added, there is no need for val2 in the first array. This optimisation causes the sort functions to copy a smaller struct, and also fit more structs in the cache, which are good. I was disappointed that this gives a few % improvement on qsort. I interpret this as qsort quickly gets chunks being sorted to a size which fits in the cache.

The same reduced-size strategy gives more than 25% improvement on heapsort.

Timing for 8 byte structs, without val2:

```
qsort(data, number-of-elements=40000000, element-size=8)
Sorting by val - duration =            16.087761
Re-order to idx by copying - duration = 2.858881
Sort in-order data - duration =         1.888554
Total duration = 20.835196
User Time:       20.417285
System Time:      0.402756

mergesort(data, number-of-elements=40000000, element-size=8)
Sorting by val - duration =            22.590726
Re-order to idx by copying - duration = 2.860935
Sort in-order data - duration =         0.577589
Total duration = 26.029249
User Time:       25.234369
System Time:      0.779115

heapsort(data, number-of-elements=40000000, element-size=8)
Sorting by val - duration =            52.835870
Re-order to idx by copying - duration = 2.858543
Sort in-order data - duration =        24.660178
Total duration = 80.354592
User Time:       79.696220
System Time:      0.549068
```

**WARNING**: Those are single runs. Many runs would be needed to get reasonable statistics.

Comment: Making that transformation completely defeats the OP's reason for doing the sort in the first place. Also, this data isn't going to fit in the cache anyway, so I suspect you're going to be paying for such things. (Even 40 million `int`s is going to be 160MB)

Comment: @Billy ONeal - my suggestion of spliting the struct is firstly to get some evidence. I think some stats would help the discussion. If the sort is cache & hence memory bandwidth limited reducing the size of the data can have a big effect. The experiment should take a few 10's of minutes to try. If it shows a tangible effect, it is worth selecting the sort on that basis.

Comment: Reducing the size of the data is useless if it doesn't solve the problem to be solved. Throwing away half the data does that.

Comment: @Billy ONeal - Agreed, fast and wrong = wrong. I haven't read an explanation of the process which leads me to your conclusion. The question says "go through an array ..., and assign the 'val' fields to be the element, and the 'idx' field to be the index." at this point, there is no val2. Sort the array, "then, once I fill in val2, reversing the procedure". Reversing the procedure resorts to idx order. As far as I have understood, we don't know what idx order was. Maybe the original idx order can be restored without a sort. I may be wrong, but the OP needs to explain the value of idx to know.

Comment: Clearly idx is just original order.  Eliminating the 2nd sort converts NlogN to N.

Answer (score 15):

Generally speaking, C++'s `std::sort` located in `algorithm` will beat `qsort`, because it allows the compiler to optimize away the indirect call over the function pointer, and makes it easier for the compiler to perform inlining. However, this is only going to be a constant factor speedup; `qsort` already uses a very fast sorting algorithm.

Do note that if you decide to switch over to `std::sort`, that your comparison functor will have to change. `std::sort` accepts a simple less than comparison returning `bool`, while `std::qsort` accepts a functor returning -1, 0, or 1 depending on the input.

Comment: Constant time speedup is fine; I'd imagine that O(N log N) casting operations aren't free.  I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: @mmr: Actually, the cast is probably free. After all, you're only causing the compiler to interpret the pointer as a different kind of pointer, not actually perform an integer conversion or anything like that.

Comment: @mmr actually casting operations do not cost anything (unless dealing with polymorphic types sometimes, or types that require conversions like float to int or something), considering that types and the type system only exist at compile time

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Another place where the cast would cost something would be something like float -> int or int -> float or similar.

Comment: @BillyONeal that is true, I was only thinking about pointer casts. But you are right, I amended my comment.

Comment: @mmr: Casting is free because it happens at compile time.  Billy is right that avoiding the indirect function call could be a big win.  (Although less than you might think on a modern CPU; Intel has gotten pretty smart about predicting branches, even indirect ones.)

Comment: I did not know that casting was free, thanks for the corrections.  I'm used to dealing with float/int casts, which are definitely not free (ie, there are side effects).

Answer (score 3):

When sorting by index, [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) might be faster than quicksort. You probably want to do it in a base that is a power of 2 (so you can use bitwise operations instead of modulus).

Comment: +1 -- BUT: Radix sort is faster asymptotically, but usually has pretty horrible constant factors in real implementations. Something worth trying, but don't think of getting rid of that extra `lg n` as a gigantic benefit. There's a reason most programming languages don't ship radix sort in their standard libraries.

Answer (score 3):

`std::sort()` should be more than 10% faster on this. However, you need two things:

1. Using a function pointer takes heroics from the compiler to detect that the function can be inlined. A function object with an inline function call operator is comparatively easy to inline.
2. In debug mode `std::sort()`'s core won't be optimized while `qsort()` is optimized a lot: try compiling in release mode.

Answer (score 1):

All the sorting algorithms are known and out there. They're easy to implement. Benchmark them.

Quick-Sort may not be the quickest in all cases, but it is pretty efficient on average. However 40 million records is a lot, sorting that in 3-4 seconds is not unheard of.

**edit**

I'll summarize my comments: It's been proven that under Turing (here, spelled right!!!) model, comparison sort algorithms are bounded by Ω(n log n). So complexity-wise there's not much place for improvement, but the devil is in the details. To discover the differences in performance of complexity-wise equivalent algorithms - you need to benchmark them and look at the results.

If, however, you have some additional knowledge about your data (for example - `idx` would be within a certain preset and relatively small range), you can use algorithms which are not comparison-sorts, and have a complexity improvement. You should still benchmark to make sure that the improvement is actually happening for your data, but for a large volume the difference between Ω(n log n) and Ω(n) will probably be noticeable. An example of such algorithms is bucket-sort.

For a more comprehensive list and complexity analysis - start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Comment: How can you tell that all sorting algorithms are known?

Comment: @SethCarnegie it has actually been proven that you cannot sort in less than O(NLogN) on a touring model without specific prior knowledge of the data (i.e.: raw sort), so even if there are additional algorithms to discover, the complexity remains the same. My point is that its up to benchmarking now to decide which would be quicker for the OP.

Comment: @littleadv: Turing, not Touring :)

Comment: So, do you have any particular algorithm in mind?  Otherwise, this answer is not much in the way of help.

Comment: @mmr - there are many, you can benchmark them all or select what's the most appealing for you. merge sort, quick-sort, radix-sort, heap-sort, you name it. If you can find some narrowing properties for the data sorted - you can improve performance by using algorithms like bucket-sort and such. Here's the comprehensive list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are sorting the `array of structures`, which means that every swap in the array is **at least two assignments** (copying of entire structures). You may try to sort an array of pointers to structures, that will save you a lot of copying (just copying pointers), but you would use more memory. Another advantage of sorting array of pointers is that you may have a few of them (each one sorted different way) - again more memory needed. Additional pointer indirection may be expensive though. You may also try to use both approaches proposed here by others together: `std::qsort` with array of pointers - and see if there is any speedup in your case.

Comment: The swap is cheaper, but all those indirections are expensive. I suspect any method involving pointers will be significantly slower than what the OP posted.

Comment: Every comparison would also require an extra indirection through a pointer.  So while I agree this is worth trying, it might not help and could even hurt.

Comment: One win here is that you don't have to do two sorts since you can keep the original array.

Comment: @Nemo: Two indirections actually -- one for the left hand side and one for the right. Plus the cost of allocating the space to contain the pointers and initialize those pointers. Plus the cost of any other indirections that the client needs to use to actually use the data in question.

Comment: He may also try both approaches at the same time: using C++ std::qsort with array of pointers and see if there are any benefits

Comment: @stark-- that's a really good idea, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Take wverything Billy ONeal said, and add the consumption of cache, and the cache bandwidth. When structs are sorted directly, neighbours are likely to be in the same chache line. But with pointers to the elements, you have a real chache buster. The data set is way bigger than cache, so it may be cache/memory bandwidth that is the killer

Comment: @gbulmer I'm not arguing with what Billy ONeal said, but I do not agree with what you said. What exactly do you mean by *neighbours* ? In case of qsort you are accessing elements in an array which are *most of the time* pretty far from each other. I also wrote that in his case it is a matter of experimenting, and pointed out advantages and disadvantages of my proposition. Again: in his case: experimenting will help, not an academic discussion.